# Correlation between multivariate random variable and univariate random variable

Tags: correlation, random-variable

Suppose you have a univariate random variable, $X$, and a bivariate random variable $Y = (Y_1, Y_2).$ What does the notation

\begin{equation}
Cov(X,Y) = 0
\end{equation}

mean? Does it mean

\begin{equation}
Cov(X,Y_1) = 0 \hspace{0.5cm}\& \hspace{0.5cm} Cov(X,Y_2) = 0?
\end{equation}

Example of where this notation is used (Poole, West, Harrison: Applied Bayesian Forecasting and Time Series Analysis [I will find page number when I can]):

The general univariate dynamic linear model is written as

\begin{equation}
Y_t = F'_t\theta_t + \nu_t, \hspace{1cm} \nu_t \sim N(0, V_t), \\
\theta_t = G_t\theta_{t-1} + \omega_t, \hspace{0.48cm} \omega_t \sim N(0, W_t), \\
(\theta_0 \mid D_0) \sim N(m_0, C_0).
\end{equation}

The two stochastic series $\{\nu_t\}$ and $\{\omega_t\}$ are assumed to be temporally independent and mutually independent, i.e. $Cov[\nu_s, \nu_t]$, $Cov[\omega_s, \omega_t]$, $\forall s \neq t$, and $Cov[\nu_s, \omega_t]$, $\forall s,t$ are zero. Here $\omega_t, \forall t$ is a multivariate random variable, and $\nu_t, \forall t$ is a univariate random variable.

Comment: Many of our posts about [covariance matrices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+matrix) will tell you that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ is a *matrix.*  By definition, a matrix is zero if and only if all its components are zero.  I do not see how your quotation is relevant, because it explicitly refers to a *univariate* model, whence you may assume all the random variables are scalar-valued.

Comment: Univariate in univariate dynamic linear model is referring to the response, $Y_t$, being univariate, not the state vector, $\theta_t$, and hence not the vector random variable $\omega_t$.

Comment: Thank you: I see that the quotation does make that explicit in the very last line.